# How to Call Button from List view inside fragment layout

Tags: android

Hello i have problem with button not updating,

I had used sample search , when user search any word ,

I had placed star button in right aligned in

I means to say suppose i search something and list view opens and at right star bookmark is there so on click it must show.

Comment: any code that you have tried?

Comment: show some code you are doing everything in air only

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any useful replies without posting your source code.